# Why am I not able to transfer data between two JFrames?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield

I have two `JFrame` within a project.
 In `JFrame1` I have one `JTextField` (`JFrame1_JTextField`) and one Button. In another `JFrame` I have only one `JTextField` (`JFrame2_JTextField`).

When I run the program and enter text in `JFrame1_TextField` and click the button, I want the text to be displayed in `JFrame2_JTextField`. But no text is displayed in the second `JFrame`.

I am not getting any error but I am also not getting the expected output.

Expected output: I want the text entered in `JFrame1_JtextField` to be set into `JFrame2_JTextField` after clicking the button.

```
private void ButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    new JFrame2().JFrame2_JTextField.setText(this.JFrame1_JTextField.getText());
    new JFrame2().setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 1):

Your code creates two new `JFrame2`s.

```
new JFrame2().JFrame2_JTextField.setText(this.JFrame1_JTextField.getText());
```

Here you created a new JFrame2 and set the text content.

```
new JFrame2().setVisible(true);
```

Now you create yet another new JFrame2 and show it. The text content has been put in the JFrame2 you created before, so obviously the 2nd JFrame2 can't display it.

Store your JFrame2 in a variable and use that:

```
JFrame2 jframe2 = new JFrame2();
jframe2.JFrame2_JTextField.setText(this.JFrame1_JTextField.getText());
jframe2.setVisible(true);
```

Communication via public variables is problematic on it's own, but that wasn't the scope of the question. Still, please consider writing public methods in your JFrame classes that you can use for data exchange.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind help.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please click the grey check mark next to my answer, in order to inform others that your problem is solved. [How does accepting answers work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)